# How can I separate the last layer of deep network in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

My deep network is:

```
self.actor = nn.Sequential(
   nn.Linear(state_dim, 256),
   nn.Softplus(),
   nn.Linear(256, 256),
   nn.Softplus(),
   nn.Linear(256, action_dim),
   nn.Softplus())
```

Now, I would like the network to give two separate outputs, like this:
[image: demo network]

That's to say, only the last layer of the network is different and maybe the last layer has different activation functions.
How should I change my code above?

Answer (score 1):

The model you want to build is not sequential anymore, since there are two parallel branches at the end. You can keep the common trunk and separate with two additional *separate* layers. Something like:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()

        self.actor = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(state_dim, 256),
            nn.Softplus(),
            nn.Linear(256, 256),
            nn.Softplus())
      
        self.outA = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(256, action_dim),
            nn.Softplus())

        self.outB = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(256, action_dim),
            nn.Softplus())
  
    def forward(self, x):
      features = self.actor(x)
      return self.outA(features), self.outB(features)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how should I change my learning part? Now the Model() has three different networks (self.actor, self.outA, self.outB), and my learning method before is: self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([
    {'params': Model.actor.parameters(), 'lr': lr_actor}
])

Comment: You can create diffferent optimizer groups with the same optimizer (*i.e.* different learning rates for different sub-modules). Look at this [documentation page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#per-parameter-options) for details on that. For the training loop, you will just do: `optim.zero_grad(); loss.backward(); optim.step()`.